# Are there any data modeling tool besides ORACLE DESIGNER that allows you to link entities of different schemas?

Tags: oracle, data-modeling

Here at our company we are still using oracle designer to model our databases, once our databases are very coupling we need to share the entities between schemas. We would like to migrate to another more uptodate tool but we haven't found any one that allow this kind of usage.

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html), perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, you can definitely build a relational model that has > 1 schema, and we don't care what schema your table is in when designing relationships/FKs. Note that an entity is in a logical design...where there are no schemas

Comment: also, it's Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler

Comment: Ah, right; I call it just "Data modeler" so I did bother to include "Oracle" along with it, but didn't bother to write its real name. Sorry & thank you, I fixed it.